# Minimum Sampling Frequency for a 20-term expression

Tags: fitting, fourier-analysis

How can I determined what the minimum sampling frequency should be for the 20-term expression for the function

```
f[t_] = (4/Pi) Sum[(1/n) Sin[2 Pi n t], {n, 1, Infinity, 2}]
```

where n= 1,3,5,10,20[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How can I sample all plots at ten times that frequency

Comment: **EDIT:** If you truncate the infinite series at `m` terms then the highest frequency component has frequency of `2 Pi (2m-1)`. That is, you have band limited the signal to a frequency of `2 Pi (2m-1)`. The minimum sampling frequency for the band limited signal is the [`Nyquist rate`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate) (twice the highest frequency component) which is then `4 Pi (2m-1)`. Ten times this would be `40 Pi (2m-1)`.  In your case you specified `m = 20`.

Comment: Following what @BobHanlon says, just take samples of all the functions with 1,3,5,10,and 20 terms, at spacings $1/(1560\pi)$ in (0,1).

Answer (score 2):

I am not clear what you are after. This is an investigation rather than an answer.  If I do

```
e = (4/Pi) Sum[(1/n) Sin[2 Pi n t], {n, 1, Infinity, 2}]
```

I get a closed form for the expression

```
(2 I (ArcTanh[E^(-2 I π t)] - ArcTanh[E^(2 I π t)]))/π
```

Which appears to be a complex expression. So I do

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[ReIm[e]]]
```

and get

```
{(Arg[1 - E^(-2 I π t)] - Arg[1 + E^(-2 I π t)] - 
  Arg[1 - E^(2 I π t)] + Arg[1 + E^(2 I π t)])/π, 0}
```

Which shows it is actually real. I can plot this and get

```
Plot[Re[e], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can you explain where your 20 terms are? This just seems to be a square wave with period 1.